# How can I handle the state of a checkbox in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a checkbox component in my react app and change the state when it is clicked. I keep getting infinite loop too many re-renders.

```
const [landlord, setLandlord] = useState(false)
```

```
return (
<form class="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

<Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
<Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Are you a landlord?" value={landlord} defaultChecked={false} checked={setLandlord(true)} /> </Form.Group>

</form>
)
```

Any idea why this is failing.

Comment: `checked={setLandlord(true)}`  You want a function pointer here, not a function call: `checked={() => setLandlord(true)}`

Comment: Do you want `value` to be `landlord`? Seems like `value` should be static. And then `checked` should be `landlord` and then you need an event handler like `onChange` to call `setLandlord`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to write:

```
<Form.Check
 type="checkbox"
 label="Are you a landlord?"
 value="true" // prob something more meaningful
 defaultChecked={false}
 checked={landlord}
 onChange={() => setLandlord(!landlord)}/>
```

Note that checked is just an attribute, not an event handler.
Also checkbox value should *normally* be static. If you're setting it to `true` then it's likely supposed to be `value="true"` or you probably don't need it.

Comment: Would you want the onChange to be `setLandlord(!landlord)`?

Comment: @im_baby otherwise `setLandlord(true)` will likely make it uncheckable because `checked={landlord}`. I haven't tested it though

Comment: unfortunately, I am getting the same error with too many re-renders. react limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

You provide `setLandlord(true)` as value of the `checked` attribute. But it should be the actual one from the state.

The `setLandlord` is the function that changes the value of `landlord`. So, it should be called on click event. Something like that

```
<Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Are you a landlord?" value={landlord} defaultChecked={false} checked={landlord} onChange={setLandlord} />
```

The